# Rails 2 “script/plugin” install git://github.com…git throws cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a rails 2 app and I'm trying to upgrade to Rails 3.1.0 first.

After doing a bit of research, I found this plugin:

```
https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade
```

Which states that the first I have to install a plugin with:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git
```

However, I get this error:

```
/home/bogdan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)
from /home/bogdan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from script/plugin:2:in `<main>'
```

My script/plugin file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require 'commands/plugin'
```

I can run `script/server script/console or script/dbconsole` with no problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: rails 2 doesn't like ruby 2, I would use ruby 1.8 or 1.9 until you've upgraded to rails 3.  What is in `script/plugin`?

Comment: @japed I edited my question.

Comment: Which ruby version is the rails 2 app currently using? Use that version to perform the upgrade. I am guessing it is ruby 1.8.7? It should just work, I did the same a few years ago when updating an old rails 2 app.

Comment: @nathanvda nope, it's 2.1.5 with rails 2.3.18.

Comment: 2.1.5 because that is what you've loaded it on, originally it will have been on ruby 1.8.7

Comment: this is how everybody on the team runs it.. don't ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't think that would be the answer but use ruby 1.8.7.

Using an old rails 2 app with ruby 1.9.3 or 2 `script/plugin` doesn't work, with 1.8.7 `script/plugin` does for me

Comment: Ok, I switched to ruby 1.8.7 with rails 2.3.18 but now I cannot run 'bundle install'. I get this error: usr/bin/bundle:7:in `require': no such file to load -- bundler. What am I missing here?

Comment: run `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem...ran all over and found the oddest solution

```
./script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade.git
```

and I kept ruby 1.9.3p194 and rails 2.3.14
no 1.8.7 needed